# How to send a Parse objectId through an Android Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, parse-platform

I am working on an Android app with a Parse backend.  The app allows a user to select a row from a list view (driven by parse data) and transition to a detail activity.  I would like to pass the ParseObject's objectId from the selected listview cell to the detail activity by using an intent.  I can easily pass most information, such as the name, but it doesn't seem to send the objectId, despite being shown as a String on the Parse Dashboard.  How does everyone else handle this?

Sending Side:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventDetailActivity.class);
ParseObject singleEvent = groupArray.get(position);
String parseID = (String) singleEvent.get("objectId");
i.putExtra("name", parseID);
startActivity(i);
```

Receiving Side:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
eventName.setText(i.getStringExtra("name"));
```

Comment: You can use `.getObjectId()` to get Id in Parse. Ex: `String objectId = gameScore.getObjectId();`

Comment: Thanks, Hoang! Put that in an answer and I'll upvote you.  I'm awarding Hardik's answer because that worked as well.

Comment: Thanks, Felker. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not possible to send `ParseObjectId` using `Intent`.
It's possible to pass the string `ParseObjectId` using `Intent` and then to next screen to again convert into a parse object as shown below.

```
    ParseObject object = new ParseObject("ClassName");
    object.getObjectId().toString();

    String str_obj = object.getObjectId().toString();

    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.putExtra("objectId", str_obj);

    // in next screen
    String getObj;
    getObj = getIntent().getStringExtra("objectId");

    ParseObject oo = new ParseObject("ClassName");
    oo.setObjectId(getObj);
```

Otherwise, it's stored as `public` and may be used in the whole application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.getObjectId()` to get Id in Parse like this:

```
 ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
 String objectId = gameScore.getObjectId();
```